# Column based flexbox that makes use of all horizontal space

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a set of checkboxes which are created alphabetically as flexbox items of a row-direction flexbox:

*Even though I have specified a width and height here, these are not fixed and will change as the browser window size is changed.*

```html
    <div style="width:500px; height:400px;">
    <div style="background-color:#99F; display: flex; flex-direction:row; flex-wrap:wrap;">
      <div style="border:1px solid #f00; min-width:170px; max-width:33%; flex:1 1 170px;"><input type="checkbox">Text A</div>
      <div style="border:1px solid #f00; min-width:170px; max-width:33%; flex:1 1 170px;"><input type="checkbox">Text B</div>
      <div style="border:1px solid #f00; min-width:170px; max-width:33%; flex:1 1 170px;"><input type="checkbox">Text C</div>
      <div style="border:1px solid #f00; min-width:170px; max-width:33%; flex:1 1 170px;"><input type="checkbox">Text D</div>
      <div style="border:1px solid #f00; min-width:170px; max-width:33%; flex:1 1 170px;"><input type="checkbox">Text E</div>
      <div style="border:1px solid #f00; min-width:170px; max-width:33%; flex:1 1 170px;"><input type="checkbox">Text F</div>
      <div style="border:1px solid #f00; min-width:170px; max-width:33%; flex:1 1 170px;"><input type="checkbox">Text G</div>

    </div>
    </div>
```

https://codepen.io/Stu42/pen/MWWvxYJ

I've set it up so it can grow to a maximum of three columns or stays as one or two columns when the space is restricted:

```
min-width:170px; max-width:33%; flex:1 1 170px;
```

I'm very happy with this responsive behaviour, but ideally the direction is `column` instead of `row`, in order to maintain alphabetical readability. For example: three columns should be like:

```
    A D G
    B E
    C F
```

And not:

```
    A B C
    D E F
    G
```

So basically, the question is, is it possible (and if so, how), to achieve this same behaviour in a column direction so that the text is alphabetical from top to bottom? I find that I cannot seem to tell flexbox to use all available horizontal space when specifying a `column` direction.

*Note: Changing the way the text is generated is not trivial, especially because you can't know if how many columns you have; never the less, for completeness, this is how:*

```html
    <div v-for="(item, index) in list_of_values" :key="index" ...
```

Comment: If you want to go with flex-direction: column, then you need to specify a height for the inner div - right now it just grows as much as it needs to, and flows out of the height of the parent container. Flex wrapping only becomes applicable, if you limit the flex container dimension in the flow direction.

Comment: yes, unfortunately.. I guess the answer is that it isn't possible without a hard height value.

Comment: Have you looked into _CSS columns_? You’d have to specify the number of columns, but maybe that can be done dynamically based on the overall number of items you have. At least you would not have to mess with the source order of the items, or hack them into multiple different blocks.

Comment: @04FS: Had never heard of it, but it turned out to be the perfect solution! I had to add page-break avoid statements for it to play nice with the checkboxes. Will post the appropiate solution code as soon as I figured the alignment out.

Comment: "Perfect"-ish.. at least. Margin control is a bit painful, and browser support seems to be a bit problematic. But I think this is the best achievable at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**CSS columns**

Altough it's use is not without issues of its own. In this scenario, the margin between the columns doesn't seem to be exactly controllable. But that's not too bad.

Thanks to 04FS for the suggestion.

Example of the solution (where the width of 500px is really the variable):

```
<div style="background-color:#99F; width:500px; margin:0px; padding:0px">

<div class="col-container">
    <div class="col-item"><input type="checkbox">Text A</div>
    <div class="col-item"><input type="checkbox">Text B</div>
    <div class="col-item"><input type="checkbox">Text C</div>
    <div class="col-item"><input type="checkbox">Text D</div>
    <div class="col-item"><input type="checkbox">Text E</div>
    <div class="col-item"><input type="checkbox">Text F</div>
    <div class="col-item"><input type="checkbox">Text G</div>
 </div>

</div>
```

The margins are largely ignored:

```
.col-container {
  background-color:#9F9;

  -webkit-columns: 3 200px;
  -moz-columns: 3 200px;
  columns: 3 200px;

  -webkit-column-width: 200px;
     -moz-column-width: 200px;
          column-width: 200px;

  -webkit-column-gap: 0em;
     -moz-column-gap: 0em;
          column-gap: 0em;

   margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.col-item {
  border: 1px solid #f00;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;

-webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
          page-break-inside: avoid;
               break-inside: avoid;

}
```

https://codepen.io/Stu42/pen/MWWvxYJ

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can specify it as a flex column, and then set a `max-height` to force the wrap at the point you would like.

```css
.page-container {
  width:515px; 
  height:400px;
}
.flex-container {
  background-color:#99F; 
  display: flex; 
  flex-direction:column; 
  flex-wrap:wrap; 
  max-height: 600px; 
  align-items: center;
  width: auto;
}
.flex-item {
  border:1px solid #f00; 
  min-width:170px; 
  max-width:33%;
  flex:1 1 170px;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="page-container">
            <div class="flex-container">
                <div class="flex-item"><input type="checkbox">Text A</div>
                <div class="flex-item"><input type="checkbox">Text B</div>
                <div class="flex-item"><input type="checkbox">Text C</div>
                <div class="flex-item"><input type="checkbox">Text D</div>
                <div class="flex-item"><input type="checkbox">Text E</div>
                <div class="flex-item"><input type="checkbox">Text F</div>
                <div class="flex-item"><input type="checkbox">Text G</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: this requires a hard height value, and doesn't take all available width automatically and therefore isn't responsive.

Answer (score 0):

You have to give a height to the container which holds the flex styling (Try giving that a height of 400px) and set `flex-direction: column`. Also, the Flex item wil to `flex: 0 170px` so it won't take the full height of the container if their are no equal items.

```
<div>
    <div style="background-color:#99F; display: flex; flex-direction:column; flex-wrap:wrap; height: 500px">
      <div style="border:1px solid #f00; min-width:170px; max-width:33%; flex:0 170px;"><input type="checkbox">Text A</div>
      <div style="border:1px solid #f00; min-width:170px; max-width:33%; flex:0 170px;"><input type="checkbox">Text B</div>

    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: this requires a hard height value, and doesn't take all available width automatically and therefore isn't responsive.